# How to bind SecurityManagerService to security domain

Tags: java, security, jboss

I'd like to know how to associate (to bind), in jboss AS, a custom SecurityManagerService to a specific security domain.
Basically I need to have two different SecurityManagerService configurations for two different security domains defined in the login-config.xml as application-policy section.

In other words, is there any way to specify the SecurityDomainService in this xml section?

```
<application-policy name="myDomain">
    --
</application-policy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears I cannot have two different instances of JaasSecurityManagerService running on jboss AS , having a different configuration, i.e. different value of DefaultCacheTimeout.
After a couple of attempts I got this exception:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: SecurityProxyFactory
```

I had a look at the JaasSecurityManagerService, this is the block of code which causes the exception:

```
SecurityProxyFactory proxyFactory = (SecurityProxyFactory) securityProxyFactoryClass.newInstance();
  ctx.bind("java:/SecurityProxyFactory", proxyFactory);
  log.debug("SecurityProxyFactory="+proxyFactory);
```

No words, they put the jndi value SecurityProxyFactory hard-coded with no possibility to change it!
I have no other choice than extend the JaasSecurityManagerService